# What is this song from Naruto song sung in Korean?

Tags: naruto, theme-song

I watched [this show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKHq6zYnNrk) and they're singing the Korean version of an OST, and although it's familiar, I can't recognize it. Seems like it's from Naruto though.

Can anyone remember the title of this song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think [i found it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ugu4C3pIquU)?? it's called Gliding by Buzz and this is the [original version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOOabRjfo-Y) of the song.

Answer (score 3):

The song's name is Gliding by Buzz.

Comment: i'm a fan of BTS myself and the one I linked in the video isn't their song, but Naruto's opening song. this one (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Wn85Ge22FQ) is their Run MV.

Comment: I think I've got the song.